# Turning XML string into List of Objects using Linq

Tags: linq-to-xml

I am attempting to turn an XML string into an a regular collection of .net Objects using Linq (I hate linq... Mainly because I have little time to learn precisely how it works, and consequently, I am always confused as hell when things go wrong).  I wish there was a nice and easy way using like an XSD or something, and some kind of deserializer, and reserializer... But there doesn't seem to be any native support in .net.  So I figured, why not just use Linq?  Big mistake.  But anyway,  I want to to turn this string...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <ArrayOfPopulation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Population>
  <id>3</id>
  <name>CHF</name>
  <description>FR Congestive Heart Failure</description>
  <createdDate>2011-10-25T04:00:00Z</createdDate>
  <createdUserID>WPS_ANEMIA_POP_OWNER</createdUserID>
  <modifiedDate>2011-10-31T04:00:00Z</modifiedDate>
  <modifiedUserID>WPS_ANEMIA_POP_OWNER</modifiedUserID>
  <isActive>true</isActive>
  <owner>
    <type>AD GROUP</type>
  </owner>   
  <owner>
    <type>ACCOUNT</type>
  </owner>
  <type>
    <name>ACO SURVEY</name>
  </type>
  </Population>
  <Population>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>COPD</name>
  <description>FR Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease</description>
  <createdDate>2011-10-25T04:00:00Z</createdDate>
  <createdUserID>WPS_ANEMIA_POP_OWNER</createdUserID>
  <modifiedDate>2011-10-31T04:00:00Z</modifiedDate>
  <modifiedUserID>WPS_ANEMIA_POP_OWNER</modifiedUserID>
  <isActive>true</isActive>
  <owner>
    <domain>1UPMC-ACCT</domain>
    <name>InteropDev</name>
    <type>AD GROUP</type>
  </owner>
  <owner>
    <domain>1UPMC-ACCT</domain>
    <name>ACOPopulationUsers</name>
    <type>AD GROUP</type>
  </owner>
  <owner>
    <domain>1UPMC-ACCT</domain>
    <name>muesml</name>
    <type>ACCOUNT</type>
  </owner>
  <owner>
    <domain>1UPMC-ACCT</domain>
    <name>andersonjm</name>
    <type>ACCOUNT</type>
  </owner>
  <type>
    <name>ACO SURVEY</name>
  </type>
 </Population>
 </ArrayOfPopulation>
```

Into an array of these objects...

```
public class PopulationModel
{
    public string populationID { set; get; }

    public string PopName { set; get; }

    public string Description { set; get; }

    public int PopulationType { set; get; }

    public int isActive { set; get; }

    //public List<XSLTACOData> patients { set; get; }
}
```

Which would kind of look like this...

```
public class PopulationsModel
{
    public List<PopulationModel> Populations { set; get; }
}
```

I am failing to do this using this linq to XML query...

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlFromSvc);
XElement elem = xDocument.Element("ArrayOfPopulation");
//client.GetOwnedPopulations();
IEnumerable<PopulationsModel> popModel = (IEnumerable<PopulationsModel>)
     (from templates in elem.Elements("Population")
      select new PopulationModel
      {
          populationID = templates.Attribute("id").Value,
          PopName = templates.Attribute("name").Value,
          Description = templates.Attribute("description").Value,
          PopulationType = int.Parse(templates.Attribute("").Value),
          isActive = int.Parse(templates.Attribute("isActive").Value)
      }).ToList();
```

I am officially confused.  Why on earth doesn't this work?  Also, there has to be an easier way to get this done?  This seems like the perfect thing for xsd's and all that other crap.  I am working to hard here perhaps?

Now getting this exception...

```
Unable to cast object of type  'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FocusedReadMissionsRedux.Models.PopulationModel]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FocusedReadMissionsRedux.Models.PopulationsModel]'.
```

This seems like a slightly more reasonable exception.

Comment: Well it would help if you'd say in what *way* it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why on earth doesn't this work?

Well, let's look at what you're doing. You've got `templates` as a `<Population>` element, and then you're querying it like this:

```
  populationID = templates.Attribute("id").Value,
  PopName = templates.Attribute("name").Value,
  Description = templates.Attribute("description").Value,
  PopulationType = int.Parse(templates.Attribute("").Value),
  isActive = int.Parse(templates.Attribute("isActive").Value)
```

Note how you're using `Attribute` here for everything. Now look at the XML:

```
<Population>
  <id>3</id>
  <name>CHF</name>
  ...
</Population>
```

The `Population` element doesn't *have* any attributes. It has nested *elements*. I haven't checked in detail, but changing all of your `Attribute` calls to `Element` calls may well fix everything except `PopulationType`. (It's not clear *where* you're trying to get that from.)

Note that the explicit conversions from `XAttribute` and `XElement` are generally cleaner to use than `int.Parse` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was refactoring this code from something else, and forgot to change the Attributes to Elements.  That being said, I am getting this error...
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FocusedReadMissionsRedux.Models.PopulationModel]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FocusedReadMissionsRedux.Models.PopulationsModel]'.

Comment: I guess that is where I am getting a little bit of confusion as well... I am looking to create a list of these PopulationModel's the inanely named PopulationsModels (just refactored to populationModels).  But this is where My linq understanding goes write out the window.  I thought that was what I was doing?

Comment: @DmainEvent: You've got a cast, but that won't work, because a `List<PopulationModel>` *isn't* an `IEnumerable<PopulationsModel>`. Work out which you want, and be consistent with it.

Comment: Is there any way you can test LINQ expression to see what you are getting?  That is probably one of the reasons I am having a hard time getting a grasp of what is going on with these LINQ querries.  I just can't grasp where I am going wrong sometimes

Comment: is it free... If not, its not going to happen, might as well take a look.

Comment: BTW, That LINQPad is looking pretty good.  I will keep it around just so I can debug my LINQ statements...
What did you think of my question BTW?

Comment: @DmainEvent: As a question? Fairly reasonable, although a short but complete example would have helped.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get value using `Attribute` method, when they are actualy elements.

Try this one (I haven't tested it to be honest):

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlFromSvc);
XElement elem = xDocument.Element("ArrayOfPopulation");

var popModel = (from templates in elem.Elements("Population")
                select new PopulationModel
                {
                     populationID = (string)templates.Element("id"),
                     PopName = (string)templates.Element("name"),
                     Description = (string)templates.Element("description"),
                     PopulationType = (int)templates.Element("Type").Element("Name"),
                     isActive = (int)templates.Element("isActive")
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you think of my question btw?  Hate to troll for points, but I am starving here.